# In meteor how do you make an API request

Tags: api, http, meteor

I am trying to get `JSON` data  from SportsRadar using an API request. My trial url is: 
http://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2018/03/03/schedule.json?api_key=4j9ge4a4rgsbq597f29p9rgb

When I copy this url into my google browser, the data I get back is as expected, but when I try to use/add the API request to my meteor project the API request does not return any data.  As a test, in my `client/main.js` file I have added:

```
HTTP.call('GET',Meteor.absoluteUrl("http://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2018/03/03/schedule.json?api_key=4j9ge4a4rgsbq597f29p9rgb"), 
   function(err,result){
      console.log(result.data);
   });
```

The console log result come back as null.  Any guidance or thoughts will be appreciated - cfp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call your callback function correctly. Try this;

```
HTTP.call('GET','http://api.sportradar.us/nba/trial/v4/en/games/2018/03/03/schedule.json?api_key=4j9ge4a4rgsbq597f29p9rgb'), 
   function(err,result){
      if (result) {
         console.log(result.data);
      }
      console.log(err);
   });
```

Edit: The parameters of The `HTTP.call()` is corrected by removing `Meteor.absoluteUrl()`in the question upon Derrick's comment below.

You can also refer to the official documentation [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call).

Comment: The above is correct except for Meteor.absoluteUrl should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for the remendations, I am still geting null data return. I think it is the api itself,  other APIs I've tested seem to work...I will look for a different sports scores api to use, any recommended Sports APIs are welcomed.

Comment: @chris Have you tried the edited version of the answer. It should work.

Comment: originally it did not work, but tried again and it did.  Thank you.